ValueError at /producto/crear_producto/ Cannot assign "<Departamento: sebas>": "Producto.departamento" must be a "Departamento" instance
Hola buenas soy nuevo aqui y tengo este problema que no se como resolver
ValueError at /producto/crear_producto/ Cannot assign "<Departamento: sebas>": "Producto.departamento" must be a "Departamento" instance.

Buenas, para ayudarte, debes incluir el código en donde se produce el error, con esto obtener un [mcve] y asi poder ayudarte.

El error menciona que tratas de asignar un Producto a un Departamento, cosa que no se puede.

Deberias de mostrar el codigo para ayudarte, pero me parece que estas tratando de asignar algun valor el cual no puede ser aceptado, por ejemplo cuando intenas agregar un string en una variable que espera un entero.
